# React Native Spotify api getting a users playlist

Tags: javascript, react-native, api, spotify, react-native-flatlist

Hi I'm currently working on a react native app and I'm trying to get a users playlist and then return it in a flatlist. I've completed getting a users access_token but I'm a little stuck on figuring out how to actually use the data. I'm fairly new to using api data.

```
export default function SpotifyGetPlaylist(props) {
    const { colors } = useTheme();

    const [token, setToken] = useState('');
    const [data, setData] = useState({});

    React.useEffect(() => {
        getData();
    }, []);

    const getData = async() => {
        setToken (await AsyncStorage.getItem('@access_token'));
        console.log("token retrieved")
    }

    const handleGetPlaylists = () => {
        axios.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/playlists", {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
        }).then(response => {
            setData(response.data);
            console.log(response.data)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    };
}
```

This part works fine and returns data into the console as such

```
Object {
    "collaborative": false,
    "description"  : "Maailman – Päivittäinen katsaus siihen, mitä kappaleita kuunnellaan eniten juuri nyt.",
    "external_urls": Object {
        "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/playlist/37i9dQZEVXbMDoHDwVN2tF",
    },
    "href"  : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/37i9dQZEVXbMDoHDwVN2tF",
    "id"    : "37i9dQZEVXbMDoHDwVN2tF",
    "images": Array [
        Object {
            "height": null,
            "url"   : "https://charts-images.scdn.co/assets/locale_en/regional/daily/region_global_large.jpg",
            "width" : null,
        },
    ],
    "name": "Maailman – Top 50",
    "owner": Object {
        "display_name" : "Spotify",
        "external_urls": Object {
            "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/user/spotify",
        },
        "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/spotify",
        "id"  : "spotify",
        "type": "user",
        "uri" : "spotify:user:spotify",
    },
    "primary_color": null,
    "public"       : true,
    "snapshot_id"  : "NzAzNDIxMzk0LDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDY2Njk=",
    "tracks": Object {
        "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/37i9dQZEVXbMDoHDwVN2tF/tracks",
        "total": 50,
    },
    "type": "playlist",
    "uri" : "spotify:playlist:37i9dQZEVXbMDoHDwVN2tF",
},
```

But I'm having problems actually rendering anything into the Flatlist which at the moment looks like this.

```
const renderItem = ({item}) => {
    <Item title={item.name}/>
}

return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button 
            onPress     = {handleGetPlaylists} 
            color       = "#1DB954" 
            style       = {{ color: colors.text, width: 100 }} 
            title       = "Get your playlists"/>
        <FlatList
            data        = {data}
            renderItem  = {renderItem}
            keyExtractor= {(item) => item.id.toString()}
        />
    </View>
)
```

I'm unsure how I get the data from the api my hunch is that I would have to use data.items.name to access it but it doesnt work for me. Help is much appreciated

Comment: Are you trying to render the tracks of the playlist or the playlist itself? It looks like this doesn't include the tracks, and you have to make a separate API call to get them. See response.data.tracks

Comment: @Abe Hey. I'm trying to render a list of playlists that the user has created. So for example I have 5 playlists with different names I'd like to render them all in my flatlist, but I haven't been able to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is appearing in the FlatList render because you're not returning your Item.  Because you have curly braces around the body of the function, you have to explicitly return the component.

```
const renderItem = ({item}) => {
    return <Item title={item.name} />;
}
```